Open graph image in text messages
I'm trying to have the app's logo appear when the link to the website is sent in a text message (SMS)
Here are my meta properties
<title>MyApp</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="MyApp">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="%VITE_FRONTEND_HOST%">
<meta property="og:image" content="%VITE_FRONTEND_HOST%/logo1200x630.svg">
<meta property="og:height" content="630">
<meta property="og:width" content="1200">

The image appears on open graph checking sites, on twitter, facebook etc., but it won't appear in text messages, which would be the most important for me.
I cannot find any information on what specific properties or image resolution text messages require.

Try a png or other raster format instead of SVG. Also make sure all URLs are absolute.
